# Volume and play controls for HTML5 Background Video

Tags: javascript, html, video

I'm using the HTML5 Background Video script (https://github.com/Victa/HTML5-Background-Video), and I'd like to be able to add some volume/play controls. I tried integrating solutions I found for other HTML5 video players, to no avail.

Minimally, I'd like a mute/volume control. Play/pause/stop would be optionally cool.

Here's the script calling the video:

```
 var videobackground = new $.backgroundVideo($('#bgVideo'), {
            "align" : "centerXY",
            "path" : "video/",
            "width": 1280,
            "height": 720,
            "filename" : "cows",
            "types" : ["mp4", "webm"]
        });
```

The site where I'm using the video is a Bootstrap template, and is located here: http://harbourcitydevelopment.com/beef/samples/sample-04/

Thanks for any ideas!

Comment: Perhaps you could try calling `.play()`, `.pause()`, etc. on the resulting video element?  BTW, nice webste you have there.

Comment: That helped, thanks! As soon as I read your comment, I realized where I'd gone wrong. Ended up adding controls="true" to the JS file for the background video, which did the trick.

Comment: ;D  Wow, I actually got something right...  Would you mind closing this question if that did the trick?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In the file 'jquery.backgroundvideo.min.js', I just added `muted="true"` and `controls="true"`, and it did the trick. Thanks to Atutouato for the suggestion with .play(), .pause(), which put me on the right track!